# For holochain rust, when does it make sense to break an app into more than one Zome?

Tags: holochain, holochain-rust

So let's say I have an app with two resources `User` and `Messages`. Currently, these resources are in their own zomes, where each Zome has only one entry. But now I am thinking about moving everything into one zome (to reduce code and logic repetition), so one zome with two entries (`User` and `Message`). Is this a bad way of structuring an hApp? How should I decide whether an Entry deserves its own zome?

Comment: I feel like this is more art than science. On principle I would say your current structure is best -- but you want your code organisation to work for you in the long run, not against you. It should bring more clarity than yak-shaving. What sort of code and logic repetition are you getting bogged down with?

Answer (score 1):

zomes are the lowest level of composition in the Holochain ecosystem.  You want to break things into zomes so you can re-use them in other places.  So the answer to your question is: put them together if your idea of a user is tightly bound to your idea of a message.  Put them is separate zomes if you think you would use your message or user zome in another project.